# Compiler error when creating new object and setting properties on it immediately

Tags: c++

I have following code

```
Parameters[FilterMorph] = new KnobCtr(processorEditor)->SetId("FilterMorph")->SetBounds(100, 100)->AddAttachment();
```

The error message is:

```
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '->'
```

but if i do it as follows

```
KnobCtr * ctr = new KnobCtr(processorEditor);
Parameters[FilterMorph] = ctr->SetId("FilterMorph")->SetBounds(100, 100)->AddAttachment();
```

all is good 
why is this so?

Parameters  is pointer map

Comment: What type does `Parameters` have ?

Comment: `new` applies to the whole expression I guess, not just the `KnobCtr`

Comment: I edited your title, I hope that's ok. Please consider how it summarises the problem more completely than your original title.

Comment: As a sidenote you should understand that when you reserve memory using `new` you should release it using `delete` at some point. This is (close to) impossible in your first code snippet but in the second one a simple `delete ctr;` will do. And besides that you should prefer a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` over a raw pointer. Or even use a plain instance if possible as in `Parameters[FilterMorph] = KnobCtr(processorEditor).SetId(...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), you need to add a parenthesis around `new`:

```
Parameters[FilterMorph] = (new KnobCtr(processorEditor))->SetId("FilterMorph")->SetBounds(100, 100)->AddAttachment();
```